# apk build successfully but app is crashing on launch

Tags: android, react-native, expo, release, eas

App is working correctly in development and on building to apk in using "eas build -p android --profile preview" the app builds successfully with no specified errors, but app breaks in production without even passing the splash screen.

On run npx expo-env-info:

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
Binaries:
Node: 20.5.0 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node.CMD
Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 9.8.1 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841
npmPackages:
@expo/webpack-config: ^19.0.0 => 19.0.0
expo: ^49.0.0 => 49.0.11
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.72.4 => 0.72.4
react-native-web: ~0.19.6 => 0.19.8
Expo Workflow: managed
```

On run npx expo-doctor:

```
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Didn't find any issues with the project!
```

**Error output**
While lauching on an andriod device it returned this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvYh.jpg)

I have tried debuging using andriod studio, and also building, it builds successfully but still the same issue.

I have also tried updating and upgrading all packages same issue

Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "yoris",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.341.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/lato": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/oswald": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "*",
    "@react-md/divider": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@sanity/client": "^5.2.1",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "@volkenomakers/react-native-country-picker": "^1.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.2.2",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1381.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "camelize": "^1.0.0",
    "canvas": "^2.11.0",
    "countries-list": "^2.6.1",
    "country-list": "^2.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.8",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-radio-button": "^1.0.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^9.17.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "native-base": "^3.4.25",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.38",
    "qrcode-generator": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^2.7.3",
    "react-google-places-autocomplete": "^4.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.1",
    "react-md": "^5.1.4",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.8.21",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animated-splash-screen": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-art": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^8.4.3",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-calendar": "^0.13.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1293.0",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.38",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-currency-input": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-fit-image": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-autocomplete": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-header-scroll-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-phone-code-select": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-responsive-linechart": "^5.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-sliding-up-down-panels": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swipe-up-down": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.6",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1",
    "twrnc": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "uid": "^2.0.1",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "yup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: You can logcat to check what's the cause of error. Connect your android device to your system using adb and then run adb logcat --buffer=crash in the terminal. Now open your app and crash log will be in terminal.

Comment: It seems that you have installed 2 packages which have Date Picker module. Please update your question with your `package.json` file

Comment: I have removed the two package, yet the application is still crashing on production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you've included four different packages for handling date pickers in your project:

```
@react-native-community/datetimepicker
react-native-date-picker
react-native-datepicker
react-native-modal-datetime-picker
```

To fix your issue, you should only keep the one that best suits your needs and remove the others from your project.

Additionally, I saw that your `package.json` file includes many unnecessary packages. These extra packages can make your app's file size larger and can potentially cause errors. So, please be mindful when adding libraries to your project. If you decide to use a different library and no longer need the old one, make sure to remove it. This will help avoid conflicts between different libraries that use the same methods.

Comment: Thanks alot, I have been able to resolve it. I had to remove react-native-date-picker and react-native-datepicker and it's working now

Comment: is there a way to check all the packages that are not in use in your application without checking them individually?

Comment: [Depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) is a tool for analyzing the dependencies in a project to see: how each dependency is used, which dependencies are useless, and which dependencies are missing from package.json

Comment: You can just run `npx depcheck` from the project directory and it will list all unused packages

Answer (score 0):

Update your Expo SDK and dependencies, disable unnecessary third-party libraries, run your app in debug mode, and build your app from Android Studio.

Comment: I have tried this already I'm not getting any crash errors, just warnings and it's also building app successfully

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).